# How do I access the shared google analytics id in Drupal 7

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7

I am looking to use the Drupal Google analyics tracking Id in another part of Drupal to do some custom tracking.

I want to use the shared ga uA code that has been entered by the user and not create a new one. 
How do I get a programmatic reference to the GA id that the user has already entered into the GA module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ga_id = variable_get('googleanalytics_account');
```